# is this a bug in TTextLayout?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

in the code below, under windows, why with

```
aLayout.Text := '   '; (11 characters)
```

then PositionAtPoint(50,0) return 5 but with

```
aLayout.Text := ' ' (5 characters)
```

then PositionAtPoint(50,0) return 3 :(

```
var aLayout: TTextLayout;
    aMeasuredWidth : single;
    aCharCount: integer;  
begin
  aLayout := TTextLayoutManager.DefaultTextLayout.Create;
  try

    aLayout.Font.Family := 'Segoe UI';
    aLayout.Font.Style := [];
    aLayout.Font.Size := 14;
    aLayout.MaxSize := Tpointf.Create(50, 65535);
    aLayout.Trimming := TTextTrimming.Character;
    aLayout.VerticalAlign := TTextAlign.Leading;
    aLayout.HorizontalAlign := TTextAlign.Leading;
    aLayout.WordWrap := False;

    aLayout.Text := '   ';
    aMeasuredWidth := aLayout.TextWidth;
    aCharCount := aLayout.PositionAtPoint(TpointF.Create(aMeasuredWidth,0)); 

    aLayout.Text := ' ';
    aMeasuredWidth := aLayout.TextWidth;
    aCharCount := aLayout.PositionAtPoint(TpointF.Create(aMeasuredWidth,0)); 

  finally
    aLayout.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Why do you ask about `PositionAtPoint(50, 0)` in both cases when you use `aMeasuredWidth`, which of course is different for the two cases? What if you use normal letters instead of emoticons? Why do you say 11 and 5 chars when theres only 7 and 3?

Comment: just to say i ask the last chars, aMeasuredWidth is not important, what is important is that i ask the position of the last char in the rect. if i use normal letter (without surrogate) everything work fine. i say 11 and not 7 because emoticon have surrogate and then count as 2 chars

Comment: I think you make a mistake, thinking that the surrogate pairs would be counted as two characters. The result is one character for a surrogate pair.

Comment: @TomBrunberg thanks .. no i confirm you surrogatepair is count as 2 characters

Comment: Looks like PositionAtPoint uses units of code points. Or perhaps glyphs. Documentation is not clear is it. Did you look at the source. You will be able to work it out by reading the docs of the underlying platform API. Buy I also wonder about your use of hard coded value of 50. This is a recurring theme of your recent questions. Imprecision. Surely we could have a MCVE.

Comment: thanks @david, yes off course i look at the source, on windows, on D2D canvas it's quite complicate to understand. so finally i end up by doing something like this : if (Result >= 0) and (Result < atext.Length) and atext.Chars[Result].IsHighSurrogate then Inc(Result, 2); ... anyway this look strange for me .. i saw many other bug with PositionAtPoint, on ios/macos

Comment: If I were you, I'd seek to understand this, rather than doing it by trial and error.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ... i fully agree with you, i will do so when i will have some time